# Syncing our SDCard Folder with DropBox in android

Tags: android, dropbox

I want to make an Android App which will responsible for 2-Way syncing with Dropbox Server. For this I already used Dropbox SDK for getting data from particular folder and Send Data to the particular folder. But this SDK is not for 2-way syncing which demonstrate that whenever any single change will be made on the server or in Local folder it will automatically synced in background.

Please suggest me any solution regarding this subject.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to make up your mind about a syncing concept.
Usually it should look like the following:
*on initial setup: create list of existing data
*download existing data
*make list of items which are in download folder
*compare (check for missing). Upload / download missing files.

*on every sync:
* look at list of items which are in dropbox
* compare with list of items in your download folder
* decide which to download/upload (especially for conflicts where both files have been modified recently without resync.)
... etc.

Comment: Yes Aeefire I know, I can apply syncing methodology as Background Downloading Task as a Service in android, but the thing is that How can we check that any changes been made on server or at any other place.

Comment: You will have to look at the specific api and if it provides any way to check filemodified -dates and/or changed hashes, get list of existing file lists etc.

usually every good api does have such options (and i am pretty sure dropbox does.)

Comment: No I think DropBox SDK doesn't send any information about changed/modified/Added files in Dropbox.

Comment: Have you tried...
https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/index.html

Comment: Yes I already used these, it doesn't provide you for realtime changed files or added files, it only provides you to download files from a particular App Folder and Write into that.

Comment: are you sure?
that getMetadata() method returns such an object => https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/index.html
which clearly has a string variable called "modified"

Comment: This method returns metadata for every file received from particular folder. But I want all modified/Added files from DropBox.